# Xamarin.Forms.maps android not showing map using api key

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.forms

Very strange

I'm have a xamarin.forms pcl and using xamarin.forms.maps

xamarin 4.5.0.486
xamarin.forms v2.3.4.247
xamarin.forms.maps v2.3.4.247

On iOS my map is showed fine.

On Android it shows a gray box

I have an api_key from google maps api using my debug.keystore sha-1

this is my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.myapp" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
  <permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <application android:label="App1.Android" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="mykey" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks for the help

Comment: check the app output from the Android project, it may contain an error message about the API key

Comment: change the `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` key with `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY`